# import protocol: how does sh creates imported wrapping functions?

Tags: python, import

After discovering [`sh module`](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) for integrating bash (shell) into python I'm using it almost for most cases instead of short shell scripting (*sh* is basically **subprocess** on steroids, and this type of integration allows to have very "pythonic bash scripting"). Indeed, I can do something like

```
from sh import ifconfig
print(ifconfig("wlan0"))
```

Now `ifconfig` is not a part of sh module. Apparently, this function is constructed dynamically. Now I got extremely curious about how exactly this is done.

So, my question is **how it works?**

At first I thought there is a PEP describing such practice as a sort of "protocol"( similar to `__enter__()` or `next()`). But I have not found any PEP explaining this.

Comment: Naturally, next question would be whether such programming is a good or bad practice. I would rather ask to avoid this type of discussion. As for me, at least in this very specific case of importing something unknown from the command line like in case of **sh** module it seems to do the trick very well, even as we know

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

From **sh** source code:

```
# this is a thin wrapper around THIS module (we patch sys.modules[__name__]).
# this is in the case that the user does a "from sh import whatever"
# in other words, they only want to import certain programs, not the whole
# system PATH worth of commands.  in this case, we just proxy the
# import lookup to our Environment class
class SelfWrapper(ModuleType):
    def __init__(self, self_module, baked_args={}):
        # this is super ugly to have to copy attributes like this,
        # but it seems to be the only way to make reload() behave
        # nicely.  if i make these attributes dynamic lookups in
        # __getattr__, reload sometimes chokes in weird ways...
        for attr in ["__builtins__", "__doc__", "__name__", "__package__"]:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(self_module, attr, None))

        # python 3.2 (2.7 and 3.3 work fine) breaks on osx (not ubuntu)
        # if we set this to None.  and 3.3 needs a value for __path__
        self.__path__ = []
        self.self_module = self_module
        self.env = Environment(globals(), baked_args)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if hasattr(self, "env"): self.env[name] = value
        ModuleType.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "env": raise AttributeError
        return self.env[name]

    # accept special keywords argument to define defaults for all operations
    # that will be processed with given by return SelfWrapper
    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        return SelfWrapper(self.self_module, kwargs)
```

few lines later, in not **main**

```
# we're being imported from somewhere
else:
    self = sys.modules[__name__]
    sys.modules[__name__] = SelfWrapper(self)
```

Comment: I really miss a good advanced tutorial on working with **ModuleType**. Please share if you know one. I wonder if **import this** is done similar?